# Throttling requests with redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

Suppose we have a user uploading something like photos, and let's say that 20 photos get uploaded at the same time. Each of these photos would need to make a request to the backend to create them. That means that I might launch 20 requests at the same time which is a lot considering there can be other types of requests during this time.

What I want to accomplish with redux-saga is saga to put all these requests on a buffer and  launch lets say 5 at a time, when a number out of the 5 are completed like 4 (in case 1 takes too long) saga should launch the rest. There is nothing on how you would accomplish this with the tools they offer. 'Throttle' offered by saga itself is not what I am looking for taking only the latest request of that type and just ignoring the others whilst I need it to save the others and fire them at a further date

There is no way to accomplish this without writing a custom module that does this management correct?